# List table total size not same as utmost element size

Tags: html, css

I have done a table in html/css with ul tags and li instead of table. I would like to add sections below this table without hard coding their position. Normally the outer element is as big as all the space the of its sub content. In this case the utmost ul element is only as big the first level children. How can I make it as big as all it's sub content and still have the list element (table column) to be of this size? The code below is boiled down to display the specific problem.

```
<style>
li {
  height: 30px;
  width : 200px;
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Values</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Data</li>
      <li>Data</li>
      <li>Data</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `table` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css:

```
ul {display:table;}
p, li {display:table-cell;}
```